# python not executing with shell script

Tags: python, vector, dropbox, ifttt

I am using IFTTT via Alexa on the Anki Vector robot. IFTTT sends a text file my computer and launchd is monitoring the folder for any changes. W hen it detects a change a shell script is called. While I can see other parts of the shell script execute the python scripts are not called. When I execute the shell script from command line it runs correctly and executes both python scripts.

I have tried changing permissions on the shell script. I have tried various ways of calling the python scripts.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 #!/bin/sh
 # My example bash script
 #osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "Hello World"'
 cd /Users/fancher/Development/anki_vector_sdk_examples_0.5.1/tutorials/

 python3 /Users/fancher/Development/anki_vector_sdk_examples_0.5.1/tutorials/01_hello_alexis.py

  python3 /Users/fancher/Development/anki_vector_sdk_examples_0.5.1/tutorials/01_hello_world.py

  sleep 3
  rm -f /Users/fancher/Dropbox/Vector/Test2.txt
  rm -f /Users/fancher/Dropbox/Vector/.DS_Store

  echo success!
  #osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog "trap point"'
```

When I execute this from the command line it works - with vector responding with custom text in the "hello_alexis.py" and the stock "hello_world" from the tutorials. When it is called by launchd the .txt file is removed but neither python script executes.
System is MacOS 10.14.2. Z reports as illegal option in MacOS. using the -@ in ls all the files had com.apple.quarantine. Used xattr to remove. chmod to make all executable . Still no joy. Looking at console I get these reports 
    Feb 5 08:01:56 MacBFancher com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.fancher.Vector_dance.): Service only ran for 3 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 7 seconds. 
    Feb 5 08:05:40 MacBFancher com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit

Comment: This sounds like SELinux is protecting your computer from remote execution. What do you get if you run `ls -lZ` on the shell script and the python scripts? (the -Z option tells ls to report on the SELinux contexts for the specified files. -l should probably be assumed because without a long listing, that shows nothing. But you still need the -l to make it actually list the output in a format where the requested information is actually shown.)

Comment: You can and are expected to edit the question to put new information in, rather than struggling to squeeze technical detail into 600 characters. `illegal command` does not sound like you typed el ess space dash el capital ze space and then entered the script name.